# How to solve the PDF of lognormal distribution using the Normal Distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-theory

Let $X$ be $N (\mu,\sigma^2)$.Define the random variable $Y=e^x$ and find its probability distribution function. My solution is this, let $G(y)= P(Y\le y)=P(e^x\le y) =P(X\le ln y)$.Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp((x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2))$.Thus,$$P(X\le ln y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\ln y} f(x)\,dx$$Please help me with the chain rule.
 How can find the pdf?Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You have $P(X\leq ln(y))$. This is $F_x(ln(y))$. $F_x(ln(y))$ is the cdf of normal distribution with $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu_x,\sigma_x^2)$

To find $g_Y(y)$ you have to differentiate $F_x(ln(y))$. Don´t forget using the chain rule.

Comment: Please help me with the chain rule. thanks

Comment: It is $g_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_x(ln(y))=f_x(ln(y))\cdot \frac{1}{y}$, because $\left( ln(y)\right)'=\frac{1}{y}$

Answer (score 0):

This follows by the change-of-variables formula for densities: if $X$ has density $f_X$ and $g$ is one-to-one, then $Y=g(X)$ has density
$$
f_Y(y)=\bigg|\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d y}g^{-1}(y)\bigg| f_X(g^{-1}(y)).
$$